# Android SyncAdapter stuck in infinite sync loop

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I'm writing an Android Sync Adapter and basically having a problem with it syncing in an infinite loop. As soon as the sync completes it starts all over again.

Thank you,

Regards,

Akshay

```
@Override
    public void onPerformSync(final Account account, final Bundle extras, final String authority, final ContentProviderClient provider, final SyncResult syncResult) {
        Log.i("Sync result full sync = " + syncResult.fullSyncRequested);
        Log.i("Sync result " + syncResult.toDebugString());
        Log.i("Bundle " + extras.toString());

        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(3);


        final CachedDataReceiver globalStreamRefreshReciever = new CachedDataReceiver(null) {
            @Override
            protected void onComplete(int resultCode) {latch.countDown();}
            @Override
            protected void onError() {latch.countDown();}
        };

        final CachedDataReceiver newMessagesReciever = new CachedDataReceiver(null) {
            @Override
            protected void onComplete(int resultCode) {latch.countDown();}
            @Override
            protected void onError() {latch.countDown();}
        };

        final CachedDataReceiver getViewedMessagesReciever = new CachedDataReceiver(null) {
            @Override
            protected void onComplete(int resultCode) {latch.countDown();showAnyNewInboxItemAlerts(getApplicationContext());}
            @Override
            protected void onError() {latch.countDown();}
        };


        /*long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long netTime = currentTime-getLastSyncTimeStamp();
        boolean shouldSync = (netTime - getSyncInterval()) >=0;
        if (!shouldSync && getSyncInterval()!=Constants.INVALID_ITEM){
            Log.i("Current time = " + currentTime + " last sync = " + getLastSyncTimeStamp() + " sync interval = " + getSyncInterval());
            Log.i("Difference = " + (netTime - getSyncInterval()));
            return;
        }*/



        if (user.isUserLoggedIn() && (!TextUtils.isEmpty(user.peekLoggedInUserAccountToken(null)))){ 
            startService(api.getGlobalStream(0,10,globalStreamRefreshReciever));
            startService(api.getNewMessagesInbox(newMessagesReciever));
            startService(api.getViewedMessagesInbox(false, getViewedMessagesReciever));
            addTimeStamp(); 
            Log.i("in sync");
            try {
                latch.await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {
                interruptedException.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error in latch while sync ");
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent network sync loop when syncing from network in Android ContentProvider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588770/prevent-network-sync-loop-when-syncing-from-network-in-android-contentprovider)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're missing a lot of code there, hard to find your problem when you don't tell us what you're doing.

Going out on a limb with a guess at your problems...

Do either `addTimeStamp()` or the various services you create modify the data stored in your ContentProvider?

If so, does your ContentProvider call `ContentResolver.notifyChange(uri, null)`?

If so, your ContentProvider notifies Android that it has changed and needs a sync, thus driving a loop.

The API is `notifyChange (Uri uri, ContentObserver observer, boolean syncToNetwork)`.  you need to call with `notifyChange(uri, null, false);` -- This indicates that you've pulled a change from the network and that it should not be pushed back to the network, thus breaking the loop.

Comment: +1 you saved me from going completely insane ... I couldn't figure it out because the notifychange code was buried deep deep undercover ;)

Answer (score 0):

when we have ContentObserver registered, the sync adapter will go in loop even after setting syncToNetwork as false.

```
notifyChange(uri, null, false);
```