# Android SyncAdapter Automatically Initialize Syncing

Tags: android, accountmanager, android-syncadapter

I have a `SyncAdapter` for my app, and an `AccountManager` to add my apps accounts to the Android Account Manager. My code for when I add an account to the Account Manager looks like:

```
Bundle data = new Bundle(5);
data.putString(_PEOPLE_ID, people_id);
data.putString(_FIRST_NAME, first_name);
data.putString(_LAST_NAME, last_name);
data.putString(_PLAN, plan);
data.putString(_BIRTHDAY, birthday);
Account account = new Account(username, _ACCOUNT_TYPE);
try {
    boolean created;
    created = _account_manager.addAccountExplicitly(account,
                                   _cryptography.encrypt(_SEED, password), data);
    response.accountCreated(created);
    _account_manager.setAuthToken(account, _TOKEN_TYPE, session_token);
    _model.updateActiveAccount(people_id, username, password);
    SharedPreferences.Editor settings = _settings.edit();
    settings.putString(_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.name);
    settings.putString(_TOKEN_TYPE, session_token);
    settings.commit();
    // Tells the content provider that it can sync this account
    ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1);
    final Bundle extras = new Bundle(1);
    extras.putBoolean(SYNC_EXTRAS_INITIALIZE, true);
    ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, AUTHORITY, extras, 900);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Ln.e(e.getCause());
}
```

I can add the account to the Account Manager successfully through Settings, but I have to manually enable syncing for the account in Settings also, even though background data and sync automatically settings are enabled on the emulator. If I manually enable syncing, then the sync is performed fine, it just isn't started by default.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1);
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, AUTHORITY, true);
```

As [Blehi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11090837/910718) said will initiate the automatic syncing of the given account, given the global Settings, "Background data" and "Auto-sync" are enabled.

To prevent the back-to-back syncing ([from jcwenger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8153280/910718)) make sure that if any method in the
`SyncAdapter.onPerformSync(...)` calls `ContentResolver.notifyChange(...)` it uses `ContentResolver.notifyChange(uri, observer, false)` to flag the notify not to trigger a sync call (the third parameter is `syncToNetwork`).

If you're using the `ContentProvider` to perform the inserts/deletes/updates for you `SyncAdapter` it makes sense to call `ContentResolver.notifyChange(...)` so that while the app is visible the user can receive updates from the `SyncAdapter`, which means you will have the `ContentProvider` making `ContentResolver.notifyChange(...)` calls. To get this set up to work, I've added (following the [dev guide](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html)) `CALLER_IS_SYNC_ADAPTER` query parameter to every URI that is used for the `SyncAdapter`. Add this method to the `ContentProvider` to test the incoming URIs

```
/**
 * Determines if the given URI specifies that the request is coming from the sync adapter.
 * @param uri the given URI
 * @return true if the uri specifies that the request is coming from the sync adapter
 */
private boolean callerIsSyncAdapter(Uri uri) {
    final String is_sync_adapter = uri.getQueryParameter(CALLER_IS_SYNC_ADAPTER);
    return is_sync_adapter != null && !is_sync_adapter.equals("0");
}
```

then you can do

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, observer, !callerIsSyncAdapter(uri));
```

whenever you need send a change notification.

And if you want to schedule the sync to be executed periodically at a frequency (polling the server) add this with the `ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(...)` call.

```
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, AUTHORITY, new Bundle(), frequency_in_seconds)
```

Answer (score 14):

Just to emphasise, it seems that addPeriodicSync() ***needs*** setSyncAutomatically(), even though the documentation says that setSyncAutomatically() is only for detecting network tickles.

Note that the period will be corrected to >60s if it's less than a minute.

Answer (score 6):

You have to set the account to be syncable by default:

```
ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1);
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, AUTHORITY, true);
```

I use the above 2 lines and it is working properly.

Comment: Adding ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, AUTHORITY, true); is what I needed, but it seems that it isn't acknowledging the periodic sync. After I add an account it just keeps syncing repeatedly.

Comment: Please try to call the ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync() function with new Bundle() instead of extras.

Comment: extras is a new Bundle(), I'm even trying it without attempting to set any of the flags (Bundle extras = new Bundle(); addPeriodicSync(account, AUTHORITY, extras, 900);)

Comment: This is quite late, but what is `AUTHORITY` here?

Comment: I just figured out it's the string you have in the `android:contentAuthority` attribute in your `sync-adapter` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Initially create an account and check the sync support for the same using AccountManager. If the account supports sync then call setIsSyncable() and setSyncAutomatically().

```
AccountManager accountManager = (AccountManager) this.getSystemService(ACCOUNT_SERVICE);
if(accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(newAccount, null, null)){
         ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AUTHORITY, 1);
         ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, AUTHORITY, true);
}
```

Then you can trigger sync anytime. It will trigger.

Note: onPerformSync() of setSyncAutomatically() will be called first then only other sync request will be triggered. 
But to make force sync just add 2 extra flags.

```
Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean(
            ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
    bundle.putBoolean(
            ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
    ContentResolver.requestSync(account, AUTHORITY, bundle);
```