# Account.setPassword causing SyncAdapter infinite loop

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

There are quite a few questions considering infinite loop of android's SyncAdapter: [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080476/android-syncadapter-stuck-in-infinite-sync-loop)
[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588770/prevent-network-sync-loop-when-syncing-from-network-in-android-contentprovider)
[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17859459/infinite-sync-loop-syncadapter), but none described the problem I encountered.

---

I am setting up my sync as:

```
ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, AppConstants.AUTHORITY, 1);
ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, AppConstants.AUTHORITY, true);
ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, AppConstants.AUTHORITY, Bundle.EMPTY, 60);
```

My sync adapter supports uploading (`android:supportsUploading="true"`), which means that in my `ContentProvider` I have to check whether the data change comes from my `SyncAdapter`, and if it does, then I notify change without requesting sync to network.

```
boolean syncToNetwork = false;
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null, syncToNetwork);
```

Still my sync adapter runs in a constant loop, what another reason could there be for triggering another sync?

Answer (score 0):

In each sync I request the server for data. For each request I get an access token from my custom [Account Authenticator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html). Instead of saving a password in my account, I decided to save the Oauth2 refresh token, which can then be use to refresh the access token. With each refreshed access token the server also send a new **refresh token**, which I then update to my account:

```
accountManager.setPassword(account, refreshToken);
```

And **THAT** was the problem. Going through the AOSP codes I discovered the following `BroadcastReceiver` in the [SyncManager](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/content/SyncManager.java#211):

```
private BroadcastReceiver mAccountsUpdatedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          updateRunningAccounts();

          // Kick off sync for everyone, since this was a radical account change
          scheduleSync(null, UserHandle.USER_ALL, null, null, 0 /* no delay */, false);
     }
};
```

So what it does, on each account change (adding, deleting, setting password) a broadcast in send to trigger sync for **all** `SyncAdapter`s, not just your own!

I honestly don't know what what the reasoning for that, but I can see it as exploitable - I let my phone (with my app stuck in infinite loop) run over night, in the morning the battery was drained, but also my FUP - only the Google's Docs, Slides and Sheets apps consumed 143MB each.